# How to get a list of SSIS Project Parameters from a C# application

Tags: c#, validation, ssis, parameters

I'm working on a project to upgrade 2008R2 SSIS packages and the middle tier code that executes them to 2016.

The existing code will run any of the packages I need to work with as it uses a lot of conditional logic to determine if a variable (now project parameter) needs to be set. I would really like to simplify this middle tier code and make it more generic.

So, my question is: Is there a way to determine what the expected parameters are for any given package? I've looked at the PackageInfo.Parameters collection, but that won't give it to me as that's collection I need to add to. I'm looking for a way to query the package/project for the parameters it's expecting.

Once I get that, I can validate the required parameters have been added to the collection and return a message to the user the package can't be run if any are missing.

If there's no reasonable way to do this, then OK, I'll work around it.

Comment: A database (mdf file) should have a parameter that contains the version of the database so you can be forward/backwards compatible.  Then when you change tables/columns you can have code to handle every case.  This is not a version of SSIS but the structure of the database. In some cases you may also need a new version if the SQL Server changes.

Comment: Can we assume the package has been deployed to the SSISDB catalog?

Comment: billinkc - yes, it has been deployed to SSISDB.  I got it figured out.  The list of parameters I need to get are in the ProjectInfo class.  I was using the PackageInfo class.  Thanks for responding though.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  You need to use the ProjectInfo class and not the PackageInfo class in order to get the expected parameters.  Doing that will get you a nice list complete with the ParameterType and other useful properties.

I called a private method GetPackageInfo and let that method return 2 out parameters, catalog and project (not sure yet if I will actually need the catalog).  I loaded up a Dictionary with the parameters in the project variable just to make using and reading them a little easier.

```
// Example Code:

try
{
     pkgInfo = GetPackageInfo(sqlConnection, sCatalogName, sFolderName, sProjectName, 
     packageName, out catalog, out project);
}
catch (Exception e)
{}

Dictionary<string, object> projectParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();

foreach (var p in project.Parameters)
{
     if (!p.Name.StartsWith("CM.M3"))
     {
          projectParameters.Add(p.Name, p);
     }
}

// Now use the projectParameters to configure your package and do validation.
```